# HTML form gives odd artifact

Tags: html, forms

I'm making a form and I keep getting an odd artifact next to the textbox.
So right after the `<br>` and right before the `<textarea` the page loads `â€‹`.

What could be causing this?

```
    <input name="pasnr" type="text" value="<?=$pasnr ?>" size="79"><br>
    Commentaar: <br>
    ​<textarea name="comments" rows="10" cols="50"><?=$comments ?></textarea><br>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Change">
```

Comment: It' s very unlikely that this is the problem, but it would help to know the contents of `$pasnr` and `$comments`

Comment: psnr=`9528051460010 302177` and comments = `comment test, look there is text here!`

Comment: Is the form live online where we can look at the output?

Comment: You can find it here: http://pietrow.net/kaiser/users.php?edit=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like an encoding issue.

The Unicode character `ZERO WIDTH SPACE` is at codepoint `U+200B`. When expressed in UTF-8 this character is represented by the three bytes `E2 80 8B`. If these bytes are then interpreted as characters in the [CP-1252 encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cp1252) they appear as the characters `â€‹`.

From the position these characters appear on your page it looks like you’ve somehow introduced a zero width space character in your editor (which is using utf-8) and since you’re not specifying an encoding the browser is defaulting to CP-1252.

A simple fix in this case would be to specify the encoding of the page, either by setting a `Content-type` header, or by adding `<meta charset='utf-8'>` to your page (assuming you’re using HTML5). (Alternatively just find the character in the file and delete it).

More generally you need to make sure the encodings you use throughout your application are consistent (i.e. your pages, the database, data from form submissions). If you’re new to character encodings a good place to start is [Joel Spolsky’s article](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

Comment: Note the ZWSP should probably removed from the source no matter the encoding

Comment: @JanDvorak, ZWSP serves no useful purpose here, but neither does it cause any harm, when the character encoding is properly declared, as it should be in any case. In other contexts, ZWSP is a useful character for specifying allowed line breaks.

Answer (score 1):

Just viewed source of your page, there is simply some junk before textarea.

I bet this is UFT8 BOM(special 3char sequence at beginning of utf8 encoded file). If page source comes from text file check if there is UTF8 BOM at file beginning and save file without a BOM.

Comment: It's generated from a combination of php, mysql and html. Could it be from the stuff I put into the text field? (so the database)

Comment: I suspect it is just before the textarea tag, check from where this textarea comes from. This additional chars may not be printed in editor/viewer so check file length, or view with hex editor, or some editors can tell you if there is BOM in file

Comment: The page has U+200B ZERO WIDTH SPACE in UTF-8 encoding there. It does not mean Byte Order Mark except at the start of a file. U+200B is valid character and is not displayed (it has empty glyph). The problem is that it is interpreted incorrectly as a string of three characters in an 8-bit encoding.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela if it's a BOM character, it probably _is_ at the start of a file. However, the BOM is U+FEFF, not U+200B.

Comment: @JanDvorak, right, sorry, I was not paying attention. It is U+200B, which is not BOM under any circumstances. U+FEFF ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE is BOM when appearing at the start of a file.